# LDAP injection issue in checkmarx:

Tags: checkmarx

I am trying to develop some app and scanned my code using checkmarx and got issue under - LDAP injection in the below method.

```
Update(request.getparameter("userID"))
```

we are calling this method and using request.getparameter() to get the corresponding value, checkmarx is showing issue at request.getparameter("userID"),

**Issue Description is** 
"This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in an LDAP query in method"

so following is one of the ways I tried

```java
String userID = request.getparameter("userID");
if(userID == null && userID.isEmpty){
    throw new ServletException(); 
}
else
    Update(userID);
```

with the above changes also the issue is not resolved.

Any idea to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I do not know checkmarx, but I guess that the issue is the input parameter that is not sanitized. Theoretically it's not necessary with a hard-coded literal, but I do not know how strict checkmarx is with that.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Checkmarx is correct in flagging your code as vulnerable to LDAP Injection.

**What is LDAP Injection?**

> **Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an LDAP Query ('LDAP Injection')**
>
> The software constructs all or part of an LDAP query using externally-influenced input from an upstream component, but it does not neutralize or incorrectly neutralizes special elements that could modify the intended LDAP query when it is sent to a downstream component.

Quote taken from [CWE-90: Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an LDAP Query ('LDAP Injection')](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/90.html)

**How to mitigate?**

> Protection against LDAP injections requires accurate coding and secure server configuration.
> Front-end applications should perform input validation and restrict all potentially malicious symbols. Developers can use regular expressions to validate untrusted input. The following regular expression can limit the scope of potential attacks by allowing only numbers and letters:

```
/[^0-9a-z]/i
```

> Perform filtration of outgoing data as additional level of security.
> Do not output information that is not related to application’s
> functionality. Implement correct access control on data within the
> LDAP directory, set appropriate permissions on user objects and
> disable anonymous access to directory objects.

Quote and example taken from [LDAP Injection Vulnerability | CWE-90 Weakness | Exploitation and Remediation](https://www.htbridge.com/vulnerability/ldap-injection.html)

Comment: i used regular expressions as well to validate the userID. but still the issue occured.

Comment: @vanam Can you post here the code you used to validate userID?

Comment: Thanks yaloner for your quick response.
Here is the code i tried using regular expression.




userID = request.getParameter("userID");
if(userID == null && userID.isEmpty){
    throw new ServletException(); 
}
else {
String USERID_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{3}[a-zA-Z|0-9]{1}";
 Pattern userID_Pattern = Pattern.compile(USERID_PATTERN);
 Matcher matcher = userID_Pattern.matcher(userID);
 if(!matcher.matches()){
   throw new ServletException();
  }
 else  
  Update(userID);
}

Comment: @dinky This code doesn't seem vulnerable. The reason Checkmarx does not find it is because you do not sanitize the value, you just check it. It is OK to choose this approach, and if you believe your RegEx is safe then you can mark the result as "Not exploitable".